# listbox contents empty when using inner join

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to populate a listbox with contents from 2 tables. When I try to "select all" from either table, I get results in my listbox. When I try to use the innerjoin query, the listbox is empty. No errors, just an empty box. The fields to join are customers.custID=sales.cust_id . What have I done wrong?

```
cust_cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=tires;Integrated Security=True"
    cust_cn.Open()
    'Dim selectStatement As String = "SELECT * FROM customers as C inner join sales as S on c.custID=s.cust_ID "
    'Dim b As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    'Dim adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(selectStatement, cust_cn)
    'Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
    'adpt.Fill(myDataSet)
    'Dim myDataTable As DataTable = myDataSet.Tables(0)
    'Dim tempRow As DataRow
    'For Each tempRow In myDataTable.Rows
    'lstCustSales.Items.Add(tempRow(tempRow("c.first") & tempRow("c.last") & "TIRE ID: " & tempRow("s.tire_id") & "QTY: " & tempRow("s.qty") & tempRow("s.notes")))
    'Next


    'Dim selectStatement As String = "select * from customers"
    'Dim b As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    'Dim adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(selectStatement, cust_cn)
    'Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
    'adpt.Fill(myDataSet, "customer_data")
    'Dim myDataTable As DataTable = myDataSet.Tables(0)
    'Dim tempRow As DataRow
    'For Each tempRow In myDataTable.Rows
    '    lstCustSales.Items.Add(tempRow("custphone") & "   " & tempRow("last") & tempRow("first") & " " & tempRow("address") & "   " & tempRow("zip") & temprow("custid"))
    'Next

    Dim selectStatement As String = "select * from sales"
    Dim b As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(selectStatement, cust_cn)
    Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
    adpt.Fill(myDataSet, "sales_data")
    Dim myDataTable As DataTable = myDataSet.Tables(0)
    Dim tempRow As DataRow
    For Each tempRow In myDataTable.Rows
        lstCustSales.Items.Add(tempRow("date") & "   " & tempRow("cust_id") & tempRow("tire_id") & " " & tempRow("qty") & "   " & tempRow("total") & tempRow("notes"))
    Next
```

when I go to management studio and type this:

```
SELECT * FROM customers as C inner join sales as S on c.custID=s.cust_ID where c.custphone=7146511734
```

I get the full results from both tables, limited to my phone# (correct/intended results)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with VB datasets for a very long time, there is a difference between how a client side dataset resolves each of the column names, versus how it is done in management studio. Essentially in Management Studio I am assuming that it is purely a string output, and no referencing to the column name is required.  This *could* cause an issue if there are fields in both tables with the same name.

I suggest being explicit in your select statement about the fields you actually want retrieved from the query, instead of using "**SELECT ***". This is good practice anyway as returning additional fields is a waste of resources, especially if there are BLOB fields

```
SELECT c.first, c.last, s.tire_id, s.qty, s.notes
```

Actually looking at your code again - you have a tempRow, looking for a column named tempRow(" ...  ")

```
lstCustSales.Items.Add(tempRow(tempRow("c.first") & tempRow("c.last") & "TIRE ID: " & tempRow("s.tire_id") & "QTY: " & tempRow("s.qty") & tempRow("s.notes")))
```

Comment: I replaced to "select * from" with "select c.first, c.last, s.qty" and still an empty box. At least that will help with efficiency! (but thank you for your quick response!)

Comment: did you check the second part of my answer?

Comment: I forgot to mention that.... yes, I copied/pasted code from another snippet in my form and that was fixed. still no results. sorry!

Comment: I have a line of code:"adpt.fill(mydataset), if I place code BEFORE it, the code runs.... If I place code AFTER that line, it doesn't run (changing the text property of a label control). not sure if that helps...

Comment: As I said Scott, I haven;t dabbled in VB world for a while, but the only other thing I notice different is the adpt.Fill doesn't contain a name for the table such as 'cust_sales_data'.  Now I don't believe this would make a difference, but if you did name it, then you could use that name in the following line where the DataTable is defined.  Maybe it's possible that the table isn't being returned as the '0'??

Comment: That didn't fix it either, but at least I cleaned up my code! I fixed it by creating a "view" in management studio and then running a simple query in vb. It is returning the results that I need.... thanks again for EVERYTHING!